# LyricAPI - how to get full lyrics?

Tags: php, soap

I want to use LyricAPI hosted on Wikia to get lyrics of songs. But in response I get only part of lyrics:

> Await the coming storm, behold the sign in the sun
>   Chaos upon us spawn! The arrows of time pinpoints us all
>   Oh, well the maddening laughter growing louder with the memories
>   Atoms like incense rising, like a thousand candles al[...]

How can I get entire lyrics?
Here is my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://lyrics.wikia.com/server.php?wsdl", array(
    'username'  =>  LYRIC_LOGIN,
    'password'  =>  LYRIC_PASS
));
$auth = array(
    'username'  =>  LYRIC_LOGIN,
    'password'  =>  LYRIC_PASS
);
$header = new SoapHeader('NAMESPACE','Auth',$auth,false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$song   =   $client->getSOTD();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.wikia.com/wiki/Documentation

> For legal reasons, the API is not allowed to provide full-lyrics at
>   the moment. It currently provides a fair-use sample (to verify that
>   the match is correct) and a link to the page where the full lyrics can
>   be viewed.

Comment: if you still need full lyrics, search for a lyrics database on fiverr  (i once found a lyrics db for free somewhere years ago..) but it may be not legal to display the lyrics in some countries, i would use a offshore hosting to be free of legal problems ;)